# Can't mount NTFS drive as root, but can as a user? (CentOS 7.6, MATE desktop)

Tags: mount, root, disk, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I am not an expert, but this really baffles me:
I have installed CentOS with MATE desktop and updated everything to latest using yum update.
This is a dual boot machine with CentOS on a separate HDD.
I installed ntfs-3g to be able to read and write to windows hdd - it worked fine.
Through all that I only used a usr acct, and then I'd open Mate terminal and do
su root and use yum as root, when needed.

Then, just today, in order to adjust x windows settings, I logged in as root. But surprise - the same windows hard drive is not visible any more. The drive has a name, let's call it "work". This time, however, I could only open "Computer" and find it there by its manufacturer (the same drive I was able to access before). So I click on the same HGST drive and try to mount it and I get:

"Cannot mount drive"

Just that. nothing else.

I log out as root, log in as a user, using the first acct I created, and check the same place, and sure enough I see the same "work" drive, and I can open it, read and write to it too. So everything is mounted as it should be.

Now, here's where the plot thickens:

- I try one other user acct, which I created today, just to have one that has the same name as windows acct, and I discover that from that one I can see one other disk, but not "work".

I also checked , as root, that ntfs-3g is still installed. It is and yum reports that there is no need to update.

In summary:

- As a user, lets call it "abc", I can see all drives, no problem, including all windows drives. I can use them too. I've been using only that acct since I installed CentOS about a week ago.
- As root I cannot see all drives, only C drive, but it is called something else (I believe 128GB is all that it shows me - it's a Solid state drive).
- As another user, with the same user name as on windows (let's call that user "john"), I can see one other drive, but not that "work" drive.

So one user shows all windows drives including the all important "work" drive, one user shows only one other drive (a second partition on  "C" drive, named "DataOnSSD"), and root shows no ntfs drives except for the C drive, the windows system drive.

Again, I am not an expert so I am totally stumped.

Here's an output of lsblk

```
[john@localhost ~]$ lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   2.7T  0 disk 
├─sda1            8:1    0   128M  0 part 
└─sda2            8:2    0   2.7T  0 part /run/media/abc/Work1
sdb               8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdb1            8:17   0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sdb2            8:18   0   1.8T  0 part 
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─centos-swap 253:1    0  23.6G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos-home 253:2    0   1.8T  0 lvm  /home
sdc               8:32   0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sdc1            8:33   0   100M  0 part 
├─sdc2            8:34   0 117.1G  0 part /run/media/john/D07AE4B07AE4948E
└─sdc3            8:35   0 115.7G  0 part /run/media/root/DataOnSSD
sr0              11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I can see from above that "work" drive was mounted to usr abc, but it did that automatically, so why not do it for every other user, including root? Should I proceed to do the mounting myself? (I have a strange feeling it wouldn't work)

Here's the fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Tue Mar  3 05:04:19 2020
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
# /dev/mapper/centos-root /                xfs     defaults        0 0 UUID=73b12660-9893-49dc-a92f-af7b612aa0ec
/boot                                      xfs     defaults        0 0                    
/dev/mapper/centos-home /home              xfs     defaults        0 0 
/dev/mapper/centos-swap swap               swap    defaults        0 0
```

Side question: accessing the "work" drive from CentOS always asks for password (the windows login passwd, I think - I use the same on both OS, so not sure). If I mount it using fstab, is it possible to include the password too so I don't have to type it every time?

Comment: Each partition can only be mounted once.  So if the system decides to only allow one user access to it, this may happen.   Since these are fixed disks, they could be miunted on boot with /etc/fstab. I'm not sure if CentOS has a GUI for configuring this though.

Comment: Paste your /etc/fstab. It might configure access. Root can everything, but you use the GUI.

Comment: Which drives are shown is driven by the "x-gvfs-show" mount option. Paste your fstab!

Comment: CentOSnoob, you will need to use [*this* account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/399173/centosnoob) to edit your posts and accept an answer; you've mistakenly created a [second account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/399240/centosnnob).